# How to screen capture using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, userform, screen-capture

I am trying to create a screen capture. I have a user form with a frame which I have the below code so on keypress, the frame moves around the userform

```
Private Sub Frame1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)

Select Case LCase(Chr(KeyAscii))
Case "w"
    Frame1.Top = Frame1.Top - 1
Case "s"
    Frame1.Top = Frame1.Top + 1
Case "a"
    Frame1.Left = Frame1.Left - 1
Case "d"
    Frame1.Left = Frame1.Left + 1
End Select

End Sub
```

What i want to know is,if I create another frame, lets call this frame2, and when I move the original frame over frame2, is there a way to screen print? would it have anythin to do with values of the the two frames like a cell or am I completely off the mark?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Private Sub Frame1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)

Select Case LCase(Chr(KeyAscii))
Case "w"
    Frame1.Top = Frame1.Top - 1
Case "s"
    Frame1.Top = Frame1.Top + 1
Case "a"
    Frame1.Left = Frame1.Left - 1
Case "d"
    Frame1.Left = Frame1.Left + 1
End Select

If Frame1.Top = Frame2.Top And Frame1.Left = Frame2.Left Then
    Application.SendKeys "({1068})"
    Me.Hide
    ActiveSheet.Paste 'paste somewhere
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: This works a treat. Thanks for the help. I had to make a copy of the original frame for this to work so going to work out how it will work with another box which is a different size. Thanks again for the help.